# Is it the correct way to update QML from thread using multi layer signals?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm writing a demo application to ease my QT learning curve. My aim is to update values from a thread which is running in background as a data generator. I wrote the QML and bind the C++ members to it using QT standard data binding approach, i.e. Q_Property. Currently the solution working as expected but wanted to confirm whether this is the correct way to implement the same.

**Idea**

1. Generate data in a thread (class DemoData)
2. Emitting signal to notify another class (class VitalData)
3. Emitting Q_Property signal (from class VitalData) to update UI

**Query**

1. Should I generate data and notify UI about the changes in a single class and send that class instance to a new thread? As I can use a single signal to update UI in this case.
2. Based on current design is it gonna suffer from poor performance or in worst case some data can be missed at UI part due to rapid signal-slot?

My aim is to keep the data generator class decoupled.

**Finally the Code**

```
//A data generator class - this can be altered by some other class if neccessary
class DemoData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int nextUpdateIndex = 0;

public slots:
    void generateData()
    {
        int hrValIndex = 0, spo2ValIndex = 0, respValIndex = 0, co2ValIndex = 0;

        while(true) {
            switch(nextUpdateIndex) {
            case 0:
                emit valueUpdated(nextUpdateIndex, demoHRRates[hrValIndex]);
                if(hrValIndex == ((sizeof demoHRRates) / (sizeof(int))) - 1)
                    hrValIndex = 0;
                else
                    hrValIndex++;
                nextUpdateIndex = 1;
                break;
            }
            QThread::sleep(1);
        }
    }
signals:
    //Signal to notify the UI about new value
    void valueUpdated(int index, int data);
};


//Class to interact with QML UI layer. This class only hold properties and it's binding 
class VitalData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int hrRate READ getHrRate NOTIFY hrRateChanged)

    public:
    int getHrRate() const {
        return m_hrRate;
    }

public slots:
    void getData(int index, int value)
    {
        switch(index){
        case 0:
            m_hrRate = value;
            emit hrRateChanged();
            break;
        }
    }

signals:
    //This signal actually notifies QML to update it value
    void hrRateChanged();
};

int main()
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    //Data generator class is getting linked with UI data feeder class 
    VitalData med;
    DemoData demo;
    QObject::connect(&demo, SIGNAL(valueUpdated(int, int)), &med, SLOT(getData(int, int)));

    //Standard way to launch QML view 
    QQuickView view;
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("med", &med);
    view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    view.show();

    //Moving data generator to a background thread
    QThread thread;
    demo.moveToThread(&thread);
    QObject::connect(&thread, SIGNAL(started()), &demo, SLOT(generateData()));
    thread.start();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**New code for thread exit**

```
int main()
{
    QThread thread;
    demo.moveToThread(&thread);
    QObject::connect(&thread, SIGNAL(started()), &demo, SLOT(generateData()));
    QObject::connect(qApp, &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit, &thread, [&thread](){
        thread.requestInterruption();
        thread.wait();
    });
    thread.start();
}


class DemoData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void generateData()
    {
       while(!QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested()) {
            switch(nextUpdateIndex) {
                case 0:
                 break;
            }
            QThread::msleep(200);
            qDebug() << "Thread running..";
        }

        //This quit was necessary. Otherwise even with requestInterruption call thread was not closing though the above debug log stopped
        QThread::currentThread()->quit();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the general design:

Looks good to me. Personally I always run `moveToThread` before everything else, but this should not influence the result in this case. (The only thing confusing is that you named the method `getData`. It's a setter not a getter and should be named accordingly)

However, the generation of your data is possible, but not optimal. With the `QThread::sleep(1)` you are blocking the eventloop, making it impossible to stop the thread gracefully. Instead, you should use a timer. The timer and the DemoData class will still be running on that thread, but by using the timer and eventloop. This way the QThread can still receive events etc. (For example, if you need to send data to your class later, you can use a slot, but only, if the eventloop of the thread can run):

```
class DemoData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int nextUpdateIndex = 0;

public slots:
    void generateData()
    {
        auto timer = new QTimer(this);
        connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &DemoData::generate);
        timer->start(1000);
    }

private slots:
    void generate()
    {
        //code to generate data here, without the loop
        //as this method gets called every second by the timer
    }
};
```

There is another way, if you do not want to use timers. You have to reimplement QThread and do the event processing yourself, but you should only do that when there is no other choice. You would have to override `QThread::run`.

Quitting a thread gracefully is rather easy, but depends on how your thread is built. If you have a working eventloop, i.e. no long blocking operation, you can simply call [`QThread::quit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#quit) and [`QThread::wait`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#wait). This however only works with a QThread where the eventloop is running (thus requiring a timer).

```
QObject::connect(qApp, &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit, &thread, [&thread](){
    thread.quit();
    thread.wait(5000);
});
```

If your thread does not run the eventloop properly, you can use the interruption requests. Instead of quit, call [`QThread::requestInterruption`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#requestInterruption). In your `generateData` method, you then have to use short intervals and check [`QThread::isInterruptionRequested`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#isInterruptionRequested) every time:

```
void generateData()
{
    int hrValIndex = 0, spo2ValIndex = 0, respValIndex = 0, co2ValIndex = 0;

    while(!QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested()) {
        // code...
        QThread::sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well initially I went for timer and shifted to thread to learn more about QT threads. I'm coming from a Win32/MFC/C# backgrounds, so trying all possible things in QT. Yes `getData` should be changed to a setter related name, will correct that. Finally one quick question. What is the proper way to close the thread gracefully on app exit? I can split the sleep of one second into shortest millisecond with a break check. Was trying connecting `aboutToQuit()` slot but that didn't help me.

Comment: Even QThreads have their own event loop. I'll update the answer accordingly

Comment: If I understood you correctly I need to put `while(!QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested())` to catch the interruption and fire the interruption on `aboutToQuit` signal. i.e. `QObject::connect(qApp, &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit, &thread, [&thread](){
        thread.requestInterruption();
        thread.wait(1000);
    });`

Comment: Correct. But make the wait a little longer then your loop timeout (i.e. 1100). You can leave the timeout out if you want to wait infinitely.

Comment: Could you please review the code updated in the last section of original post. The thread was not quitting until I added a call `quit()` from inside the `generateData()` function class.

Comment: If you reimplement `QThread::run`, no quit is needed, because no eventloop is running. But for your case, qutting is needed. However, you should call quit from the main thread as well, because QThread lives there! Either that or use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`

Comment: A big thank you for your continuous support. It really helped me a lot.